# Why do signed deb packages say they're not authenticated when copied to my private deb repo?

Tags: repository, deb, puppet

### Quick Version

I have set up a private deb repository and copied some signed deb packages into it. I have installed the signing key locally. However when I try to install from the repo I get this warning:

```
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
```

When installing manually, I can just press <kbd>y</kbd> but I want to install these packages automatically using puppet, and that fails.

So what's the problem? Do I need to resign packages with a key I control? Is there a better way of ensuring I have a particular version of puppet installed?

### More Details

I have got the packages from the [puppet debian repository](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/puppetlabs_package_repositories.html#for-debian-and-ubuntu) - http://apt.puppetlabs.com/ I just copy the package from (for lucid) [this directory](http://apt.puppetlabs.com/pool/lucid/main/p/puppet/)

The repository is then updated with a script that runs these commands for each repo:

```
cd /var/www/html/apt/ubuntu/lucid
dpkg-scanpackages binary /dev/null | gzip -9c > binary/Packages.gz
dpkg-scansources sources /dev/null | gzip -9c > sources/Sources.gz
```

I have installed the signing key on the client.

```
$ sudo apt-key list
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg
--------------------
...
pub   4096R/4BD6EC30 2010-07-10 [expires: 2016-07-08]
uid                  Puppet Labs Release Key (Puppet Labs Release Key) <info@puppetlabs.com>
...
```

The rationale for doing this is that I want all puppet clients to be the same version. So all machines should get the packages from my repository by using the following pin in `/etc/apt/preferences.d/puppet`:

```
Package: puppet puppet-common facter
Pin: origin deb.example.org
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

(We are currently using puppet 2.6.x, so I need a priority of 1001 to downgrade precise clients from 2.7.x).

I have read about [holding packages](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto#Introduction_to_Holding_Packages) but that doesn't help me change package versions.

All suggestions welcome.

Comment: Half an answer, and not too sure, but the Debian wiki on your way of creating the repository ([here](http://wiki.debian.org/HowToSetupADebianRepository#dpkg-scanpackages_and_dpkg-scansources)) lists it as not possible to use signed packages. See the 9 (!) alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*.deb` packages are **not** signed directly, in Debian. There is a way to do that, but nothing in Debian uses it.

The principle used by Debian and Ubuntu APT repositories instead works like this:

All `*.deb` binary packages are listed in a file (e.g.) `binary-i386/Packages.gz` with their checksums. (All current Debian and Ubuntu versions use all three(!) of MD5, SHA-1 and SHA-256 for this. Old versions used MD5 only.) All `*.dsc` source packages are listed in `source/Sources.gz`.

All these files `binary-*/Packages.*` and `source/Sources.*` are then listed, with their checksums, in a file `Release`, which is signed as either `Release.gpg` or `InRelease`, with the PGP key of the *repository*.

So basically, if you put any packages into an APT repository of your own, you will need to sign that repository, and use `apt-key add` to import your own repository's signing key into your system when you want to use any packages from that repository.